# Is the reduction map completely positive?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information

I am struggling with proving the complete positivity of a general map ( granted it is CP ).
The reduction map  is defined as
$$ \rho \rightarrow \mathrm{Tr}(\rho)I - \rho $$
It is a trivial job to show the positivity of this map. I don't know whether this map is CP at first place.

Is there some physically intuitive argument which explains why this map isn't (or is) completely positive (such as an entangled state on which it acts in a non-positive way)?  (Which is something which is not discussed in the answers to the post marked as a duplicate on math.SE.)

Comment: How is this any different from your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733835/how-can-we-show-that-a-map-is-a-completely-positive-map) (that was migrated to math.stackexchange)?

Comment: @KyleKanos Hi , The question which was migrated to math section has  been answered and it talks of Choi-Jamiolkowski-isomorphism . The issue is I don't understand why a special preference is given to E-bit in the algorithm. I want another method which is more convincing ?

Comment: Have you asked the answerer, Martin, if he could be more clear in his answer?

Comment: Okay , I would try there. Btw I would like someone to help me with more physical arguments ( as why E-bits pop up if this question is answered here in terms of Choi algorithm ).

Comment: I mean "does entropy of E-bits has anything to do with the algorithm ?"

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question.  It would allow for a nice canonical answer about the reduction criterion as a way to detect entanglement (and maybe even the general relation of positive but not completely positive maps with the detection of mixed state entanglement).  The linked answer on math does not address any of that.